# Bind to an Android Service from a Android JobService

Tags: android, android-service, android-jobscheduler, android-job

Due to Android O background services restrictions, I have to make some changes to my application's logic without affecting the behavior. 
Question: Can I bind to an android service from a Android JobService. The documentation says bound services are not affected in any way. I tried experimenting with some periodic jobs. It does look like it is working. Can some one confirm it?